# Get error before they execute the error message function

Tags: php, error-handling

I want to receive the error message in php before it gets executed. Basicly what i mean is that if I would have a bad code:

```
// This code is incorrect, I want to receive the error before it gets handled!
$some_var = new this_class_is_not_made;
```

Now that class does not exist, so it would be handles by the default error handler in php. But I want to disable the normal error handler and create my own.

Another example:

```
somefunction( string some_var ); // some_var misses the variable prefix. ( $ )
```

Example error message:

> **Fatal error:** function 'some_var' is not defined in line: $x!

And this error would be: `somefunction( string some_var );`

But how would I receive the messages but also disable the normal error system?

**EDIT**: Making the error system execute a `user-defined` function

```
// I would want the error system to execute a function like this:
function(string $errorMessage, int $error_code){
    if($error_code < 253){ return "Fatal error"; }
    if($error_code < 528 && $error_code > 253){ return "Warning"; }
}
```

**Answer found:** By: ShiraNai7

```
try
{
    // Code that may throw an Exception or Error.
}
catch (Throwable $t)
{
    // Executed only in PHP 7, will not match in PHP 5
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // Executed only in PHP 5, will not be reached in PHP 7
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP 7.0.0 or newer the code will throw `Error` exception if `this_class_is_not_made` doesn't exist.

```
try {
    $some_var = new this_class_is_not_made;
} catch (Error $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Note that that this will also catch any other `Error` exceptions in case `this_class_is_not_made` does exist and causes some other error along the way.

In PHP versions prior to 7.0.0 you're out of luck - fatal errors always terminate the main script.

It might be a better idea to use [`class_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) instead:

```
if (class_exists('this_class_is_not_made')) {
    $some_var = new this_class_is_not_made;
}
```

This works in all PHP versions that support classes.

Comment: Thats not the problem, I just need to receive the error, and im using PHP 7.0.3

Comment: Then use the try..catch or `set_exception_handler()`

Comment: Thanks for the catch one :)